# Advantages of using ES/TS syntax with AngularJs 1.x and Angular Js Material 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

What are Advantages of using ES/TS syntax with AngularJs 1.x and Angular Js Material 1? As far I know I feel this will be helpful for Angular 2/4 upgradation

Is there any disadvantages of using Vanilla JS syntax with AngularJs 1.x and Angular Js Material 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TS will probably make it easier to upgrade to Angular (2+). Other than that, there are no particular benefits in using ES6/TS over Vanilla JS for AngularJS specifically. There are the general benefits (and tradeoffs) of using ES6/TS over Vanilla JS. 
There will be no AngularJS specific problems encountered whereas using TS/ES will make life easier though for organizing code, Code understandability and so on.. as said  [here](https://blog.appdynamics.com/engineering/the-benefits-of-migrating-from-javascript-to-typescript/) and [here](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/community/the-advantages-of-typescript/).